# Different user on chat than the main site

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, chat, users

We recently received an access request in the Android room and upon looking into the user to make a decision, I noticed some strange things.

First, the user's name and avatar were different...this makes sense
as I understand it takes time for changes to propagate.

Then I noticed the rep was drastically different (23 on chat vs 2k+ on the site). After inquiring with the other owners, it was brought up that maybe the chat was a bug and it should have been 2.3k instead of 23. Maybe

But then I noticed the badges were completely different, as well. But you will notice that the user IDs are the same

Not sure what's going on here. Below are relevant images and links. I was going to try and leave the user out of it but the links are probably important and maybe I missed something.

**Chat user:**

[image]

**SO user:**

[image]

[Chat user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3426825/obey-joseph)

[SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426825/some-folk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now. There was a user merge a while ago that wasn't propagated to chat correctly. Thanks for noticing.